# Android Studio "set-debug-app" command

Tags: android, debugging

Please,tell me what should I do to debug app installed on my phone with Android Studio and "adb shell am set-debug-app" command.

Comment: please elaborate you problem you are facing

Comment: I connected my phone to computer,execute this command.Next on my device appears a window,it tell me that process is waiting for debugger to attach,in adroid studios I click on debug icon,but Android Studio does not show me any processes for debugging.@Nitesh

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vo5PXWnKtQ4

Answer (score 0):

Try to investigate these points:

1. Compile your app in debug mode.
2. You don´t really need to run `set-debug-app`. You can simply add the breakpoint, but this command is useful to avoid the "Android Not Responding" dialog.
3. Be sure you have the proper Android SDK installed in your Android Studio. For example, if your device runs Android 13, you need to install Android SDKs 33. [Here](https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platforms) is the correspondence list of Android SDKs.